# Heuristics / Solver for high dimensional planning problem

Tags: optimization, heuristics

To optimize a production system by planning ~1000 timesteps ahead I try to solve an optimization problem with around 20000 dimensions containing binary and continuous variables and several complex constraints.

I know the provided information is little, but can someone give a hint which approach would be suitable for such big problems? Would you recommend some metaheuristic or a commercial solver?

Comment: There are also metaheuristic enterprise solvers ([OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/), Local Solver, etc). Those should work too.

Comment: Thanks, is there also an open source solution available?